# how to redirect bash variable to an executable?

Tags: bash, redirect

I have an executable, say it's called `a.out`. It takes two lines of input after a prompt --

```
> ./a.out 
> give me input-1: 0 0 10
> give me input-2: 10 10 5
> this is the output: 20 20 20
```

I can store the inputs in a file (input.txt) and redirect it to `a.out`, the file looks like this --

```
0 0 10
10 10 5
```

and I can call `a.out` like --

```
> ./a.out < input.txt
> give me input-1: 0 0 10 give me input-2: 10 10 5
> this is the output: 20 20 20
```

Now I want to store multiple inputs in that file and redirect into `a.out`. The file will look like this with 2 inputs --

```
0 0 10
10 10 5
0 0 20
10 10 6
```

and I am writing a bash script like --

```
exec 5< input.txt
while read line1 <&5; do
      read line2 <&5;
      ./a.out < `printf "$line1\n$line2"` ;
done
```

It does not work, how do I do that?

Comment: It might help to describe more specifically what about your final attempt doesn't work exactly. (From a general high quality question perspective if nothing else.)

Comment: Much safer to use `printf '%s\n' "$line1" "$line2"`; that way you don't introduce bugs if anything in `line1` or `line2` reads as a format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<` requires a file name containing content, not the content itself. You probably just want to use a pipe:

```
exec 5< input.txt
while read line1 <&5; do
    read line2 <&5
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" | ./a.out
done
```

or a process substitution:

```
exec 5< input.txt
while read line1 <&5; do
    read line2 <&5
    ./a.out < <(printf "%s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2")
done
```

You don't need to use a separate file descriptor, though. Just redirect standard input to the loop:

```
while read line1; do
    read line2
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" | ./a.out
done < input.txt
```

You might also use a here document (but note the indentation):

```
while read line1; do
    read line2
    ./a.out <<EOF
$line1
$line2
EOF
done < input.txt
```

or a here string:

```
while read line1; do
    read line2
    # ./a.out <<< $'$line1\n$line2\n'
    ./a.out <<<"$line1
$line2"
done < input.txt
```

The newline can be included using the special `$'...'` quoting, which can specify
a newline with `\n'`, or the string can simply have an embedded newline.

---

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can use the `-t` option to detect the end of the input, so that `a.out` can read directly from the file.

```
# read -t 0 doesn't consume any input; it just exits successfully if there
# is input available.
while read -t 0; do
    ./a.out
done < input.txt
```

Comment: A `HERESTRING` would also work (without needing a sub-shell).

Comment: I was just about to add a here string, but then decided to just add a here document, since embedding a newline in the here string requires either Yet Another New Syntax (`$'...\n...'`) or something that looks almost exactly like a here doc anyway.

Comment: OK, I caved on the here string, since I realized process substitution was probably also worth mentioning.

Comment: `-t` would be my preferred option.

Comment: Copying `printf "$line1\n$line2\n"` from the OP is bad juju -- if anything in either of those lines is a format string...

Comment: Agreed; I'm not sure why I let that slide in my answer.